# MongoDB Database Design Upvote and Downvote

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a collection of Posts and Users where users can upvote/downvote each post. I am trying to store the id of the posts that each user has voted on.(As suggested here [storing upvotes/downvotes in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147686/storing-upvotes-downvotes-in-mongodb?rq=1))  I have this mongoose schema and it works fine for now:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    votedPosts : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Posts'}]
  });
```

But now I want to add an extra piece of information, I want to store if the vote is a downvote or an upvote, I tried storing -1/1 depending on the vote type but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    votedPosts : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Posts', votetype: Number}]
  });
```

Any suggestions ?

edit: So it seems like its simpler when I get rid of the 'ref: Posts' part, now my code looks like this:

```
  var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    votedPosts : [{ _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , votetype: Number }]
  });
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, because I don't reference the posts collection anymore.

Comment: does `User.findById(id).populate('votedPosts')` work?